# sum of squares of the first n odd numbers

Tags: python

I was given an assignment to find the sum of the squares of the first n odd numbers whereby n is given by the user.

The assignment was;

```
The script only takes one input, so do not
# include any input command below. The print commands below are already given.
# Do not alter the print commands. Do not add any other prints commands.

r = range(1, n + 1)         # prepare the range
result = 0                  # initialise the result
for k in r:                 # iterate over the range
    result = result + k     # update the result

  compute the sum of the squares of the first n odd numbers, and print it
```

This is what I have done so far;

```
r = range(1, n ** n, 2)         
result = 0                  
for k in r:                 
    result = result + k
```

I know the range is wrong because when I ran it, I used 5 as n and I expected the answer to be 165 because the squares of the first 5 odd numbers is 165 but instead I got 144.

Please help

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You aren't taking the first `n` odd numbers, or squaring them. Perhaps you should start by breaking the problem down: step one, can you create a list or iterator of the first `n` odd numbers?

Comment: sum(k*k for k in range(1, 2*n, 2))

Comment: @babyblue That's the whole code that you need (except for the input of `n` and the print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to do iterate through odd numbers so if we want to do n odd numbers we need to go up to 2*n.  For example, 5 odd numbers would be 1,3,5,7,9 and 2*5=10, but we only want every other number so we have the command `r = range(1, n * 2, 2)`

We then start with zero and add to it, hence `result = 0`

Now we iterate through our range (r) and add to our result the iterator squared, hence `result = result = (k * k)`

Overall we have:

```
r = range(1, n * 2, 2)
result = 0
for k in r:
    result = result + (k * k)
print result
```

Comment: I'm writing to you as a reviewer because your answer has been flagged for its quality. When you submit an answer would you please explain your code and, if possible, show typical results that can be obtained with it. We value your input and improvements like these would make a lot of difference to future readers of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = range(1, n + 1,2)
print r
result = 0                  
for k in r:                
result = result + k ** 2
print result
```

if you pass n=5 then it will print 35 because the range is 1,3,5 and during iteration it skip the step 2,4..you are considering like 1,3,5,7,9=165 but actual result will be 35 so instead of n=5 you can pass n= 7 so when you will pass n=7 then range will be [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] and output will be 165

Comment: Please add this explanation in the answer itself. By itself, the answer is pretty low quality.

Answer (score 0):

`n**n` is n to the nth power. So with `n=5`, your range is all the odd numbers between 1 and 3125. It should be odd numbers between 1 and 10.

```
r = range(1, n ** n, 2) 
#               ^ replace n**n by ...
```

You want to sum squares, so you should compute squares :

```
result = result + k
#                   ^ something is missing here
```